# Type conversion in Java (Double / double)

Tags: java, type-conversion

Please explain how type conversion in Java (Double / double, Integer / integer, ...) works.

Why is only the last example valid?

```
     setLocation(double, double);

     // This don't work
     player.setLocation((Double) jsonMsg.get("x"), (Double) jsonMsg.get("y"));

     // This don't work too   
     player.setLocation((double) jsonMsg.get("x"), (double) jsonMsg.get("y"));

     // It's ok!
     player.setLocation( Double.parseDouble(jsonMsg.get("x").toString())
                       , Double.parseDouble(jsonMsg.get("y").toString())
                       );
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: assuming - `jsonMsg.get("x")` returns a String, you need to parse the String as a Double value. example : "123.22" needs to be parsed as a double. This isn't typecasting. This is *parsing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your `jsonMsg.get("x")` returns an **object** which string representation can be converted to a double type value.

And your `setLocation` method needs two `double` type parameters, i.e declared as

```
setLocation(double a, double b)
```

To convert strings to double you need to invoke `Double.parseDouble()`. It parses parameter string to a double value and returns it.

**UPDATE:**

in java it is not possible to cast an object variable to a primitive type. So you need to invoke a parsing method of a `Double` class to convert this string object to a double type value.

Answer (score 0):

Java do type conversion implicitly between Wrapper class(Integer,...) and Primitive type (int,...) after Java 1.5.

but what you're trying to do in the first two steps is to cast Object/String into Double which is not allowed and need explicit manipulation like Double.parseDouble(jsonMsg.get("x").toString()) or new Double("1.2").

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notice: `String` is a object and if you want to convert object type to primitive type you have to use **wrapper/covering classes**. You **cannot do casting**.

Java has wrapper classes for every primitive data types. As a example:

> int   - Integer
>
> double - Double

Wrapper classes have methods to manipulate primitive data types and to convert objects to primitive data types. As a example:

> For int - Integer.parseInt()
>
> For double - Double.parseDouble()

In your code snippet last line:

`Double.parseDouble(jsonMsg.get("x").toString()`

you are parsing String to double it is correct and in other two line you are trying to cast. In one using wrapper class:

`player.setLocation((Double) jsonMsg.get("x"), (Double) jsonMsg.get("y"));`

and other one using primitve type:

`player.setLocation((double) jsonMsg.get("x"), (double) jsonMsg.get("y"));`

Both are incorrect. Because of `jsonMsg.get("x")` returns `String` object. You have to convert it into String using `.toString()` and parse it to `double`.

Notice: `toString()` method is used when we need a string representation of an object.

I hope you get the point.

Comment: How do you know what `jsonMsg.get("x")` returns?

Comment: Sorry for that mistake @shmosel. I were refering git repo and editing this answer

Comment: Who said `jsonMsg` is a `JSONObject`?